# jQuery else if with Ajax

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I want to say else if (delete_box is clicked) how can I do that in the else if (currently empty)? They both (man and delete_box) have the same purpose but if you click on one or the other then something slightly different happens.

```
$(man).add(delete_box).click(function(){ 
        if(App.manager != true){
            overlay.fadeIn('fast',function(){
                box_2.animate({'top':'200px'},500);

                    $('#manager_pass').submit(function(evt){ 

                        evt.preventDefault();

                        data = {
                            managerPassword: $('#token').attr('value'),
                            action: 'passwordManager'
                        };

                        App.manager = $('#token').attr('value'); // set the manager token to the one inserted so that it's stored inside the page

                            $.ajax({
                                url: App.URL_manager,
                                data : data,
                                dataType: 'json',
                                type: 'POST',
                                success: function(r){
                                    if (r.success) {
                                           box_2.animate({'top':'-250px'},500,function(){
                                           overlay.fadeOut('fast');
                                           });

                                            $('.action_wrapper').fadeOut(1000,function(){
                                                    $('.add_staff').fadeIn(1000);
                                            })
                                    }

                                    else {
                                            $('#manager_pass').fadeOut(1000,function(){
                                                $('.error').fadeIn(1000);
                                            })
                                         }
                                }

                            });

                    });


                });
        }

        else if()

        else{
            action_wrapper.fadeOut(1000, function(){
                $('#add_staff').fadeIn(1000);

            })
        }


});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is` method.

```
$(man).add(delete_box).click(function(event){ 
    // ...
    else if ($(event.target).is(delete_box)) {
       // ...
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9gcdQ/